# Possible to have different Longest Common Subsequence for same pair of Strings?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**I have two input strings:**

String1 = `3 9 8 3 9 7 9 7 0`
String2 = `3 3 9 9 9 1 7 2 0`

Now, If I assess **Left-To-Right**, then LCS obtained : `3 3 9 9 7 0`
But, If I assess **Right-To-Left**, then another possible LCS: `3 9 9 9 7 0`

Here's a picture to explain it (hopefully) better:

[image]

**I wanted to understand if this is normal, or am I making a mistake ?**

my code for generating LCS is below, which gives the Right-To-Left scenario output:

```
private static String[][] memo; // memoization

public static String lcsMemoized(String[] p, String[] q, int pLen, int qLen) {
    String result = "";
    // base case
    if (pLen == 0 || qLen == 0) return "";
    else if (memo[pLen][qLen] != null) return memo[pLen][qLen];
    else if (p[pLen - 1].equals(q[qLen - 1])) {
        // common last character
        result = lcsMemoized(p, q, pLen - 1, qLen - 1) + p[pLen - 1];
    } else {
        String op1 = lcsMemoized(p, q, pLen - 1, qLen);
        String op2 = lcsMemoized(p, q, pLen, qLen - 1);
        if (op2.length() > op1.length()) result = op2;
        else result = op1;
    }
    memo[pLen][qLen] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? There are apparently multiple sequences that fit the bill, and your algorithm is picking one of them by random, whichever sequence it encounters first. If you search for *all* longest common subsequences, both directions should return the same list, maybe in a different order.

Comment: Fun question: what happens if you reverse the strings as well as the direction?

Comment: @CShark i get `0 7 9 9 3 3` which is like my `Left-To-Right` version, only reversed, which makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only can there be multiple LCSs, there can be many.  Consider the string of length `2m`, `1 2 1 2 1 2 ... 1 2` and another string of the same length, `2 1 2 1 2 1 ... 2 1`.  The two of these have `2m` LCSs!

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to have two or more LCS.
A trivial example: 1231 and 1321 have 2 LCS: 121 and 131.